# Term for the identification of the person speaking in a dialogue

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, dialogue

Consider the following piece of dialogue:

> **Peter:** Hello, Mary! How do you do?
>   **Mary:** Hi, Peter! Fine, and you?

What is the term for the part in bold, the specification of who is to speak a particular line?

Comment: These seem to be called "character names" in screenplays. I've checked several [formatting guides](http://www.scriptfrenzy.org/howtoformatascreenplay) for screenplays, and they all seem to use this (rather obvious) terminology.

Comment: @PeterShor This would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interlocutors: The persons who take part in a dialog.

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain, will be this term "designation the interlocutors" clear?

Comment: There are other synonyms. "Interlocutor" is precise, but may sound high-brow or supercilious. "Speakers" is also good enough.

Comment: You may say "The speakers (or interlocutors) are..." Does that help?

Comment: Nearly. But I need to say something like: " `xxx:` - is the designation of interlocutors in dialogue" - will be this clear?

Comment: If I could chat here, I would, but I don't know how. I suppose you are trying to say something like this: **Peter, Mary, (and) John: the interlocutors (in the dialog).** Parenthetical terms are optional.  If you are introducing or summarizing the transcript of a conversation, you may say this. I think showing you how to say it more completely can be handled in a separate questions or at one of the other language forums.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7261/discussion-between-andremoniy-and-jim)

Comment: Perhaps ***xxx:** identifies the speaker in dialog* would be a simpler way of putting it. "Designation" is a slightly obscure term that doesn't really fit here (it's more *the name by which something will be known*, rather than *the format in which something will be written*).

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the name for the text that says who is speaking, in screenplays these seem to be called "character cues" or "character names". I've checked several [formatting](http://www.scriptfrenzy.org/howtoformatascreenplay) [guides](http://www.storysense.com/format/cues.htm) for screenplays, and those that have a term for this use one or the other of these.